# TSQL: Returning a value of 'NONE' if rows don't exist

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been working with Microsoft Server Management Studio for the past few weeks and for the most part I've been able to figure everything out, but there's one major area I'm having difficulty. I'm routinely asked to run queries to find specific values for people in a given list of names. However sometimes some of the people in the lists I query over don't have the values I'm looking for, so their names aren't returned at all.

For example when I put in a list of 50 people to this query:

```
SELECT p.name, dbsr.reviewCd
FROM Person p, DbSpecialReview dbsr
WHERE p.personId = dbsr.personId 
AND p.name IN (...);
```

I might only get values for 40.

What I need is to know how to run a query such that even if only 40/50 people have values associated with them, the query returns a table containing all of their names, and if a person doesn't have a value it populates the relevant column with 'None' or 'Null'.

Comment: This is a generic SQL question, not specific to SQL Server. You should use a LEFT JOIN. Generally, the syntax you use is deprecated and JOINS are the preferred way to ... join related tables

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp would be an example if you need one.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos please don't remove the tags which may help users to give an appropriate answer.

Comment: I knew about LEFT JOIN and the joins... but I guess my skills were lacking. I think the issue is I kept using 'LEFT OUTER JOIN' when I was trying to find what I was looking for without any luck (I didn't include it in the super simple sample query I posted there because after trying it a lot without success I figured it wasn't relevant)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.name, ISNULL(dbsr.reviewCd , 'None') AS reviewCd
FROM Person p
LEFT JOIN DbSpecialReview dbsr ON p.personId = dbsr.personId 
                              AND p.name IN (...);
```

Comment: You need to switch the 'AND' to a 'WHERE' but otherwise this worked perfectly, thanks for the help my man!

Comment: @JoshKraushaar it would work either in `AND` or `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Would suggest using COALESCE here as well, instead of ISNULL.

Comment: @JoshKraushaar . . . Your advice is incorrect.  M.Ali . . . You are also incorrect.  The `WHERE` clause is the right logic.

Comment: @GordonLinoff adding the condition to `ON` clause , will it return the wrong results ? or having it in `WHERE` clause will benefit in any way ?

Comment: A condition on the first table in the `on` clause of a `left join` doesn't do anything particularly useful.